# Java Video/Music Player

Tags: java, video, audio, video-streaming

can u give me advice, which java lib i should use for playing video(H.264)/audio(mp3, aac) streams/files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Quicktime for Java](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/QuickTime_for_Java) may be your best bet, as it has many supported platforms and codecs.  The [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) has been languishing for a while.

Depending on your requirements, the [Java bindings for VLC](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) may also be useful.

Comment: wow, I'm glad I stumbled across those VLC Java bindings. Will definitely come in handy!